# sync iframe and audio stream in php

Tags: php, html, audio, iframe

I want to create a program to show `iframes` from a specific server which sends JPEG streams through HTTP and play sound from another HTTP port together and synced. I've searched in the whole forum but didn't find a straight forward answer to it.
I've created the following `HTML5` code, it works but the problem is the image streams coming earlier than voice and it is out of sync. My aim is to sync the image stream and voice together by setting a delay or buffer for image.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <IFRAME id="video" src="http://192.168.1.111:8081" width="800px" align="center" height="600px" scrolling="no" frameborder=no marginheight="0px"></IFRAME>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <audio controls autoplay>
<source src="http://192.168.1.114:8000/sound2" type="video/ogg">
</audio>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate if you post any solution to this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: there isn't any one?